# Save clipboard's contents as file and return the data to the clipboard later? Different types of copied objects

Tags: node.js, copy, buffer, clipboard, copy-paste

How can I store buffer/clipboard data from CMD+C as some kind of object or write the contents to txt file to return it later to buffer/clipboard to use CMD+V. The data might be always different like usual text, images, or aplication speficic object, for example photoshop layer (if you are within photoshop ui and do copy-paste of selected layer, it creates new layer, but if you are out of the app UI, it will just paste nothing)
I want to implement it with Node js